# Find out how much time a process is blocked waiting for I/O on Linux

Tags: linux, performance

Is there a [vmstat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vmstat) type command that works per-process that allows you to see how much time a process is blocked waiting for [I/O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input/output), time in kernel and user code?

Comment: Did you consider profiling the application with e.g. oprofile? That would give you more details about where exactly the application spends how much time (IO or otherwise).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[blktrace](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/axboe/blktrace.git;a=blob;f=README) is what your looking for, block layer information, wait/blocking/busy etc..., very in depth, there are quite a few of packages that derive from it, seekwatcher, ...

Some other tool, simular to what sigjuice said, iotop, is also handy, but less informative for serious analysis.  Also I believe btrace/blktrace is much more well suited for I/O tracing than oprofile, which is more general and increases load in comparison.

Answer (score 2):

[strace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) will show you how much time is spent in system call, however it won't tell you how much of this time is spent in waiting versus time really spent for I/O. you can select which system call you want to trace, or which type, it is quite powerful

[latencytop](http://www.latencytop.org/) would be another good tool, because your process can be waiting for I/O because of other processes, or because of some journalling daemon.

Answer (score 1):

Also look at `pidstat -d`.  It lets you see how much each process is reading and writing.

Answer (score -1):

[top (1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/top) will show this imformation.  You can specify an individual pid with `-p`

Comment: -d : Delay time interval as: -d ss.tt (seconds.tenths)
Specifies the delay between screen updates, and overrides the corresponding value in one's personal configuration file or the startup default. Later this can be changed with the 'd' or 's' interactive commands.
Fractional seconds are honored, but a negative number is not allowed. In all cases, however, such changes are prohibited if top is running in 'Secure mode', except for root (unless the 's' command-line option was used). For additional information on 'Secure mode' see topic 5a. SYSTEM Configuration File.